# calling a PHP script from Javascript to insert data to a mysql database

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

There is a button in my html file upon click I need two things to be done. (Insert data to a database and reload the page) So I call a javascript function in the onclick event.

This is the function inside the javascript file:

```
function grandFinale()
{
     if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
     {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
         xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
{// code for IE6, IE5
xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
 {
  //document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
 }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","insert.php?q=",true);
xmlhttp.send();
document.location.reload();

}
```

This is the insert.php file which is mentioned above

```
<?php
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","uname","password");
if (!$con)
  {
   die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("SnakeDB", $con);

$sql="INSERT INTO masterTable (Name, Score) VALUES ('$_GET[name]','$_POST[txtScore1]')";

if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }
echo "1 record added";

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Here is the part of HTML file which contains the places I want to update to the database

```
<div class="modal-body">
 <p>You scored :: </p><p id="txtScore1"></p>
<input type="text" placeholder="Your Name" id="name"> </div>
```

The issue is the database is not updated!! Only the reloading happens. Please suggest me a solution

Comment: Please stop writing new code with the ancient mysql_* functions. They are no longer maintained and community has begun the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799). Instead you should learn about prepared statements and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you care to learn, [here is a quite good PDO-related tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Comment: SQL injection issues there also, `$_GET['name']` and `$_POST['txtScore']` are not escaped.

Answer (score 3):

As fare as I can see didn't you send the parameters to the script?!

Append the name field also to the

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","insert.php?q=&name=" + encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('name').value),true);
```

The given code is not tested but should work this way.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to pass two values. both name and txtScore1.

Comment: @Esailija I replaced the line with xmlhttp.open("GET","insert.php?q=&name=" + encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('name').value + "txtScore1=" + encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('txtScore1').value ),true); It doesn't work!!

Comment: @PasanWijesinghe that code is syntactically invalid (You can see the errors in console) plus this is not my answer I just improved it with an edit.

Comment: the field "txtScore1" is not a form field! So you have to read it at least with ().html() or ().text(). But I may mixed now jquery into my answer.

Comment: I tried this line xmlhttp.open("GET","insert.php?q=&name=" + encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('name').value + "&txtScore1=" + encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('txtScore1').text() ),true); Till it gives a syntax error in javascript console.

Comment: Sorry. text() and html() are methods in jquery! user .innerHTML instead

Comment: Got it cleared here. Thanks everybody. It was a syntax error. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11817127/how-to-write-a-ajax-get-request-with-two-parameters-taken-from-html-file

Answer (score 1):

The error in your javascript is, that you are not sending any values to your script via ajax.

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","insert.php?q=",true);
```

`q` ist just empty, `name` and `txtScore1` are not set.

Plus in your SQL-Statement you are mixing up GET and POST values.

$sql="INSERT INTO masterTable (Name, Score) VALUES ('$_GET[name]','$_POST[txtScore1]')";

Should be written as:

```
   $sql="INSERT INTO masterTable (Name, Score) VALUES ('{$_GET['name']}','{$_GET['txtScore1']}')";
```

Warning, you should always check GET or POST data before insering it to the database!

You tagged your Question with jQuery but you aint using it. You should. It would condense your javascript to just a few lines + reloading of the page is not needed!

See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Comment: Will you please explain to me how to set name and txtscore for q.

Comment: Got it solved here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11817127/how-to-write-a-ajax-get-request-with-two-parameters-taken-from-html-file Thanks everybody

Comment: A good solution would be to wrap your input fields into a html form and use ``$("form :input").serialize();` to get the values. Using that way, you don't have to type alll the key names etc. It's even more easy for server side validating, if you would wrap all field names into an array. `myform[score], myform[name] ...` then you PHP script can access the array using `$_GET or $_POST['myform']`.