# How to write a AJAX GET request with two parameters taken from html file?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have the following HTML elements whose values I need to INSERT to a database.

```
<p>You scored :: </p><p id="txtScore1"></p>
<input type="text" placeholder="Your Name" id="name">
```

This is the sample javascript code suggested at W3schools site to get the task done.

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","demo_get2.asp?fname=Henry&lname=Ford",true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

So I tried the following lines in my javascript file:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","insert.php?q=&name=" + encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('name').value + "&txtScore1=" + encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('txtScore1').innerHTML),true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

It doesn't work and in chrome console the error is given as **Uncaught Syntax Error. Unexpected Identifier (repeated two times).**

Can you please suggest the error I'm doing?

Comment: Google chrome tells you in which lines you are getting the error. post those line so can see what is wrong with them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a syntax error.

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","insert.php?q=&name=" + encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('name').value + "&txtScore1=" + encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('txtScore1').innerHTML),true);
```

should be

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","insert.php?q=&name=" + encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('name').value) + "&txtScore1=" + encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('txtScore1').innerHTML),true);
//                                                                                                 ↑
//                                                                                        Added parenthesis
```

Comment: Glad I could help, click the checkbox next to the arrow if you want to mark this answer ass correct.

Comment: Yes. It is correct. And thanks for teaching me the etiquete since I'm new to stackoverflow.

Comment: Must have been a freudian slip by me there.